# /var/run/postgresql missing after reboot

Tags: centos, postgresql, centos7

I have Centos7 machine set up and I'm having problems with postgres not starting after reboot. Even when I try to run the service manually I'm getting

```
UTC FATAL:  could not create lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No such file or directory
```

Taking a closer look, I noticed that `/var/run/postgresql` is not event existing after the reboot.

So a couple of questions really, as I didn't find clear answers in my research.

How and when are the directories in /var/run even created, is it something that get created on starting a service or what is the way?

What could be causing this specific issue to happen and not to start postgres after reboot?

I've never seend this behavior before, although in all fairness I have been using ubuntu mostly so far.

Thanks

Comment: Centos 7 uses [systemd-tmpfiles](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tmpfiles.html) to populate `/var/run/`. Is compiled from source or rpm distribution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you examine `/var/run` on your system, you'll see that it's actually a symlink to `/run`:

```
# ls -ld /var/run
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 6 Jan 19 09:12 /var/run -> ../run
```

And if you examine `/run`, you'll see that it's actually a `tmpfs` mountpoint:

```
# mount | grep /run
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755)
```

A `tmpfs` filesystem is an in-memory filesystem: anything there disappears when the system reboots.  As Federico says in his comment, CentOS 7 (and Fedora, and RHEL 7, etc) use the `systemd-tmpfiles` facility to automatically create things like lock directories and other ephemeral storage locations when the system boots.

The `postgresql-server` package included in CentOS 7 already does the right thing:

```
# rpm -ql postgresql-server | grep tmpfiles
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf

# cat /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf
d /var/run/postgresql 0755 postgres postgres -
```

If you are using a third-party postgresql package, don't be surprised that it doesn't integrate correctly with CentOS.  You can manually correct is by setting up the same `tmpfiles.d` entry shown here.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation of /run and /var/run! Not sure why was it really happening as it was installed with yum and it was happening every time I provisioned machine, but I updated it to  postgres 9.4 as I already planned anyway and that seems to set all this up properly so I don't have to.

Comment: It works but I had to set the ownership of /var/run/postgresql to the user postgres with comand "chown postgres:postgres /var/run/postgresql". Without doing that, it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add unix_socket_directories = ' /tmp' # comma-separated list of directories into your postgresql config file. The file should be somewhere on (on RHEL 7.x & CentOS 7.x)

/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/postgresql.conf

or

/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf

then reboot the server and your postgresql service should start up without problem.